# How can I sum values from range using two criterias both with ranges using OR condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Example:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rM7gTI3yrOrtndFLlBJuwvR8AFN4ViZ08brGFfrcg40/edit?usp=sharing

I'm writing down my working hours.
In column A I have all dates, in column B I have names of all days, in column C I have values (number of hours).
In column E I have the specific days (holiday) I want to sum. In column F I have the specific days (weekends) I want to sum.

**Question:** What should be in the cell G2 to sum all holidays and all weekends **but if they overlap, only one of them**?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E2&F2; A$2:A&B$2:B; 0)+ROW(B$2)-1; 2); COLUMN(C2))&":"&
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E3&F3; A$2:A&B$2:B; 0)+ROW(B$2)-1; ROWS(C:C)); COLUMN(C2)))))
```

[image: 0]

**note that date in E column needs to be paired with correct day in F column**

to do just dates use:

```
=INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E2; A$2:A; 0)+ROW(B$2)-1; 2); COLUMN(C2))&":"&
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E3; A$2:A; 0)+ROW(B$2)-1; ROWS(C:C)); COLUMN(C2)))))
```

shortened:

```
=INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E2; A$2:A; 0)+1; 2); 3)&":"&
 ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(E3; A$2:A; 0)+1; ROWS(C:C)); 3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a quite an elegant way, albeit for my specific problem:
`SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(WEEKDAY(A2:A; 2); ">=6"; C2:C)-SUMPRODUCT((C2:C)*(WEEKDAY(A2:A; 2)>=6)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A;E2:E;0)))))+SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A; E2:E; C2:C))`

This sums the hours from days with number greater than 6 (Saturday and Sunday in my country) and subtract from it the sums of hours in days that are simultaneously a weekend and from the range (holidays). That way I can get the weekends without holidays and then just add the sumproduct of holidays.

You may have to tweak the condition of weekends if you want to use it, that should not be hard.